# Setting a property for only a specific phase

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

I want to be able to set a property for a specific maven phase. How can I do that?

For example, assume that I want to set a property like this:

```
<properties>
    <spring.profiles.active>production<spring.profiles.active>
</properties>
```

only when one is executing `mvn package`. I know that I can manually set a property, but I want it to be automatic so it is not forgotten.

Comment: First as J Fabian Meier already answered that this is not possible. Second base on the given information it looks like a spring boot project. That mean you are mixing concept spring boot profiles and maven profiles which are completely different things. Using a production profile in Spring for a build area does not really makes sense..even if you have production profile...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

But probably there is a solution for the original problem you want to solve. Please write a new question which describes the use case.